# How to use the 'leave' command in Xubuntu?

Tags: bash, xubuntu

I cannot find the **leave** command in *xubuntu-terminal*. Xubuntu uses BASH by default. I'm not sure whether **leave** is not available for BASH or Xubuntu. How do I use it? Or, is there any alternative to leave in BASH?

Comment: What is "leave"?

Comment: You are not meaning `exit`, are you?

Comment: @MichaelHomer take a look here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/leave

Comment: @ThomasErker nope. leave is a package that reminds the user when to leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, leave(1) is a FreeBSD program, not a shell command.
Here is a Ubuntu package for it: [Package Search Results - *leave* | Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=leave&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

I guess it's not installed by default. You should be able to install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install leave
```